# Hibernate Annotation for TemporalType.TIMESTAMP Precision

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm creating a table using Hibernate for MySQL database in Java.

One of the columns is of Date type.

```
@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
@Column( name = "event_start_time", nullable = false, length = 19 )
public Date getEventStartTime()
{
    return eventStartTime;
}
```

I know that it's possible to specify the precision of TIMESAMP in MySQL using

```
TIMESTAMP(6)
```

However, how do you do that in Hibernate annotation mapping?  I've tried

```
length = 19, precision = 38, scale = 20
```

none of which seem to store the time in milliseconds past the second aka

```
1374839856000
```

as opposed to

```
1374839855789
```

Anyone know a solution to this?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you have to change your column type to datetime .

Comment: I don't believe there's a TemporalType.DATETIME, there's only DATE or TIME in Hibernate.

Comment: little confusion here,`1374839856000` is need you but you get `1374839855789`. Right? or something else...

Comment: No I meant I would like to have 1374839855789, but is instead getting 1374839856000

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the class you configured in property hibernate.dialect and then change the used data type there. Set the property hibernate.dialect to your new class.

This is what worked for me (since MySQL 5.6.4):

```
public class MySQL564InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {

    protected void registerColumnType(int code, String name) {
        if (code == Types.TIMESTAMP) {
            super.registerColumnType(code, "TIMESTAMP(6)");
        } else {
            super.registerColumnType(code, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there really no other solution? This looks more like some workaround. Why is it so difficult? Timestamp precision seems to me like common thing to set